# ¿Puedo utilizar código de Stack Overflow para una aplicación de pago?

Tags: soporte, licencia-del-código, legal

Buenos días a la comunidad. Mi nombre es Miguel Gutiérrez Lanza , soy venezolano y no soy programador. Solo revisando el internet voy copiando, pegando y realizo algunos programas. Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Podría utilizar un programa de esta comunidad en una aplicación que fuese paga, en especifico el programa audio-echo? ¿Cómo debo contribuir al utilizar ese programa?

Y disculpen mi ignorancia, recuerdo que no soy programador. ¿Podría incluir ese programa en otro que estoy realizando como una librería?.

Por favor les pido ayuda, artículos donde pueda instruirme.

En general soy tsu en electrónica y mi objetivo con este proyecto es realizar una aplicación en android para las personas que son tartamudas. Diseñé una aplicación libre en javaFx Y tengo el dispositivo en físico , pero quisiera que mucha gente lo utilice creando la aplicación en android y ofreciéndolo a muy bajo costo. Al menos 80% más bajo del precio de las herramientas que están en el mercado.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Que programa es ese? podrias incluir el link al programa? tendrias que revisar que tipo de licencias tiene.

Comment: Ese programa genera un eco y esa característica inicialmente ayuda al individuo con tartamudez, por eso lo quiero incluir en mi aplicación. La licencia del programa audio-echo es apache versión 2

Comment: pero esta hecho por esta comunidad? tiene algo que ver SO en eso?

Comment: Disculpe la comunidad el programa es de otro sitio. Igual su ayuda para crecer en lo relacionada a la programación en android la necesitare. Saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: ok. por favor pásate por los siguientes links para saber como funcionamos [tour] y [ask]. Aparte tu pregunta fue migrada a meta, pq aquí se hacen preguntas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. las preguntas de programación van en el sitio principal.

Comment: Ok gbianchi muchas gracias y lamento no haber cumplido los requerimientos. En futuras preguntas seguiré las reglas.

Comment: No te preocupes, todos empezamos alguna vez.. Bienvenido y ojala podamos ayudarte!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Todo código publicado en StackOverflow tiene una licencia [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.es_ES) según puedes ver en [la ayuda de este sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Copio de la web de creative-commons:

> Esto es un resumen inteligible para humanos (y no un sustituto) de la
>   licencia. Advertencia.
>
> Usted es libre de:
>
> **Compartir** — copiar y redistribuir el material en cualquier medio o
>   formato.
>
> **Adaptar** — remezclar, transformar y crear a partir del material
>   para cualquier finalidad, incluso comercial.
>
> El licenciador no puede revocar estas libertades mientras cumpla con los términos de la licencia.
>
> ### Bajo las condiciones siguientes:
>
> **Reconocimiento** — Debe reconocer adecuadamente la autoría, proporcionar
>   un enlace a la licencia e indicar si se han realizado cambios. Puede
>   hacerlo de cualquier manera razonable, pero no de una manera que
>   sugiera que tiene el apoyo del licenciador o lo recibe por el uso que
>   hace.
>
> **CompartirIgual** — Si remezcla, transforma o crea a partir del
>   material, deberá difundir sus contribuciones bajo la misma licencia
>   que el original.
>
> **No hay restricciones adicionales** — No puede aplicar
>   términos legales o medidas tecnológicas que legalmente restrinjan
>   realizar aquello que la licencia permite.
>
> ### Avisos:
>
> No tiene que cumplir con la licencia para aquellos elementos del
>   material en el dominio público o cuando su utilización esté permitida
>   por la aplicación de una excepción o un límite. No se dan garantías.
>   La licencia puede no ofrecer todos los permisos necesarios para la
>   utilización prevista. Por ejemplo, otros derechos como los de
>   publicidad, privacidad, o los derechos morales pueden limitar el uso
>   del material.